# Calling the release REST API with artifactSourceId filter not working

Tags: azure-devops

```
https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/MYTenant/Myproject/_apis/release/definitions?artifactSourceId=39b9c74f-a6c4-4676-a720-326f3238e661:4&$expand=artifacts&api-version=4.1-preview.3
```

According to the documentation I should filter on artifactSourceId but it returns all definitions for this project.

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/release/definitions/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1
```

Anything I am doing wrong? Do I need to add something?

Comment: have look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) it will help us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Including artifactType=Build in the query resolves the issue.